# Unable to add new WiFi network on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-5.0-lollipop

I used this code with Android <5.0 with no issues:

```
// //////////// save network
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
ConfigurationSecuritiesV8 conf = new ConfigurationSecuritiesV8();
conf.setupSecurity(wc, conf.getScanResultSecurity(scanResult), password);
wc.BSSID = scanResult.BSSID;
wc.SSID = "\"" + scanResult.SSID.replace("\"", "") + "\"";

int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
if (id == -1)
    return RESULT_CANT_CREATE_NETWORK;
```

I just installer the new Android 5.0 on my Nexus 5 and now I can't add network programmatically.

Comment: A comment on the downvote would be precious, becouse with android < 5.0 everything works well

Comment: I'm trying to connect Hotspot  programmatically, it is working fine till 4.4, but it is not working 5.0 and above versions. I haven't seen anything about wifi in the changes docs also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fount the problem, i need to change my code to

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    wc.SSID = "" + scanResult.SSID.replace("\"", "") + "";
else
    wc.SSID = "\"" + scanResult.SSID.replace("\"", "") + "\"";
```